# How do I create a 60 seconds countdown timer in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to create a 60seconds countdown timer in kivy. It will start immediately when the code is run and it should print 'countdown completed' when the countdown is in 0.

Have not been able to derive any code for this. I  just need a simple 60s countdown timer

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't designed to be a free code-writing service. When I do an online search for "kivy countdown timer" I get many results. Have you tried doing research before asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

As @Bryan Oakley mentioned:

> Stackoverflow isn't designed to be a free code-writing service

but I love `Kivy` so maybe this will help someone someday...

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


class countDownClock(Label):
    counter = 60
    def update(self, *args):
        if self.counter > 0:
            self.text = str(self.counter -1)
            self.counter -= 1
        else:
            self.text = "KaBoom"


class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        countdown = countDownClock()
        Clock.schedule_interval(countdown.update, 1)
        return countdown


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

Answer (score -2):

this was developed using Tkinter,

```
from tkinter import *
import time, sys
window = Tk()
window.title("Countdown")
print('\nHello\nInstructions: add time.\n')
hourz = input('Hours: ')
minz = input('Minutes: ')
secz = input('Seconds: ')
hour = int(hourz); min = int(minz); sec = int(secz)
var = StringVar()
var.set("00:00:00")
label_title = Label(window, textvariable=var)
label_title.pack()
window.update()
print('Check the window !\n')
while hour > -1:
    while min > -1:
        while sec > 0:
            sec = sec - 1
            time.sleep(1)
            sec1 = ('%02.f' % sec)  # format
            min1 = ('%02.f' % min)
            hour1 = ('%02.f' % hour)
            var.set('\r' + str(hour1) + ' : ' + str(min1) + ' : ' + str(sec1))
            window.update()
        min = min - 1
        sec = 60
    hour = hour - 1
    min = 59
print(' Finish !\n')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that this will result in a very low accuracy timer, because you're using `time.sleep()` and never synchronize to a real clock. As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), `time.sleep()` may take more or less time than required, and you're also not taking into account the time required by the rest of the code.

Comment: suggest me a good python timer module for these kinds of activities.

Comment: It should be in kivy

Comment: give a try, if any error comes ask us, don't expect full answer here...Sorry

Comment: The question explicitly asks for how to do this in kivy, not tkinter. Plus, this is absolutely not the correct way to do a timer in tkinter.